# Problem in importing external utility library in openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, external, colormap

import colormap from 'colormap';

https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/cog/colormap.html

How to use this utility in javascript?

I am using CDN of openlayers

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/css/ol.css

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to use a browser compatible version of colormap, e.g. `<script src="https://bundle.run/colormap@2.3.2"></script>`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can I render this tile on the openlayer maps?( i.e  Street View map or satellite view map)

Answer (score 1):

If the developer has not provided a browser build for an NPM package you *may* be able to use a utility such as bundle.run (see https://github.com/Rich-Harris/packd)  In this case that does work but I would suggest you download the build to your own server

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>OpenLayers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-container {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://bundle.run/colormap@2.3.2"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

const source = new ol.source.GeoTIFF({
  sources: [
    {
      // red reflectance
      url: 'https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/21/H/UB/2021/9/S2B_21HUB_20210915_0_L2A/B04.tif',
      max: 10000,
    },
    {
      // near-infrared reflectance
      url: 'https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/21/H/UB/2021/9/S2B_21HUB_20210915_0_L2A/B08.tif',
      max: 10000,
    },
  ],
});

// near-infrared is the second band from above
const nir = ['band', 2];

// near-infrared is the first band from above
const red = ['band', 1];

const difference = ['-', nir, red];
const sum = ['+', nir, red];

const ndvi = ['/', difference, sum];

function getColorStops(name, min, max, steps, reverse) {
  const delta = (max - min) / (steps - 1);
  const stops = new Array(steps * 2);
  const colors = colormap({colormap: name, nshades: steps, format: 'rgba'});
  if (reverse) {
    colors.reverse();
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    stops[i * 2] = min + i * delta;
    stops[i * 2 + 1] = colors[i];
  }
  return stops;
}

const layer = new ol.layer.WebGLTile({
  source: source,
  style: {
    color: [
      'interpolate',
      ['linear'],
      ndvi,
      // color ramp for NDVI values
      ...getColorStops('earth', -0.5, 1, 10, true),
    ],
  },
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map-container',
  layers: [layer],
  view: source.getView(),
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```